# Which sights are open late in Paris?

Tags: sightseeing, paris, nightlife

I am on a conference in Paris and I have free time after 7 pm. What can I see at this time? Last time I went up the Eiffel tower, this was great at night and still open. What else can I do?

Which sights have long opening hours?

Comment: What types of things do you like.  Do you want suggestions on dining out or just seeing the sights?  Do you want to see people, or things?

Comment: Fascinating idea, but so open-ended that it has to be considered 'primarily opinion-based', so close voted.

Comment: Open your eyes and walk till you drop.

Comment: Sorry... I meant sight seeing... No dining, rather seeing things... Thanks

Comment: The website of the Paris Convention and Visitors Bureau has a page titled “Places to visit at night in Paris”: http://en.parisinfo.com/discovering-paris/themed-guides/paris-by-night/practical-guide/places-to-visit-at-night-in-paris

Comment: Removed the 'what sights to do' as that's still subjective, but asking which sights are open at night is at least answerable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’d suggest taking a look at the website of the Paris Convention and Visitors Bureau, which has a [page titled “Places to visit at night in Paris”](http://en.parisinfo.com/discovering-paris/themed-guides/paris-by-night/practical-guide/places-to-visit-at-night-in-paris). It lists a number of places (mostly museums, some galleries) that have late openings. The page is unfortunately organized by place rather than by what your options are on a particular day of the week, but the “fact sheet” for every place does clearly list “late opening” on the “prices and times” section.

Here are a few suggestions taken from that page, but organized by day of the week (non-exhaustive list):

**Monday**: Musée Jacquemart-André (until 9pm, only during temporary exhibitions).
**Tuesday**: Jeu de Paume Paris (until 9pm).
**Wednesday**: Musée du Louvre (until 9.45pm).
**Thursday**: Musée des Arts et Métiers (until 9.30pm), Musée d'Orsay (until 9.45pm), Musée du Quai Branly (until 9pm).
**Friday**: Musée du Louvre (until 9.45pm), Musée du Quai Branly (until 9pm).
**Saturday**: Musée du Quai Branly (until 9pm), Musée Jacquemart-André (9pm, only during temporary exhibitions).

There’s also the Palais de Tokyo which is open every day, except Tuesday, until midnight; and the Musée de l'Érotisme is open every day until 2am.

Obviously these times can change, so do check the original “fact sheet”. For most places it also lists until what time before closing time the ticket offices stay open, which would be useful to know.

(Thanks for reopening this question; the above is a slightly extended version of the [answer I proposed on the meta SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/can-the-question-on-which-sights-are-open-late-in-paris-be-reopened)).

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately [ParisInfo](https://en.parisinfo.com/) (the official tourism website of Paris) has a great few pieces on this:

- [Places to visit at night in Paris](http://en.parisinfo.com/discovering-paris/themed-guides/paris-by-night/practical-guide/places-to-visit-at-night-in-paris) - many museums, theatres and more are open late, including Espace Dali, Musee d'Orsay and the Louvre.
- [Some places are open very late or all night](http://en.parisinfo.com/discovering-paris/themed-guides/paris-by-night/practical-guide/open-very-late-or-all-night-in-paris) - but this is more in terms of food, services and shopping.
- And finally their piece on [night transportation in Paris](http://en.parisinfo.com/discovering-paris/themed-guides/paris-by-night/practical-guide/night-transport-in-paris) - covering the Noctillen buses, Metro, RER, taxis and more.

Comment: downvote reason?

Comment: I was a little miffed at having someone else turn my comment into an answer even though I announced I'd post one, but I assume you didn't want to have the question reopened and then leave it without an answer; I tried to undo the downvote now, but it seems it's locked in already, sorry.

Comment: @Rinzwind oh, I didn't even realise they were the same sites, I'd simply googled after hours Paris stuff.  Meh, it happens.